# Where to buy a SIM card at Ben Gurion airport, Israel?

Tags: cellphones, israel, airport-terminals

Are there any places to buy an Israeli SIM card when at the Ben Gurion airport, in Israel?

Answer (score 3):

Based on a trip in December 2018, after posting my question, I can report there is a booth in the non-secure area of the terminal, on the ground floor (near the exit from the arrival/baggage claim/customs area) that sells 019mobile.com SIM cards at a 66% mark up over their website prices ($50 vs $30) for 2 weeks with unlimited international calling and 2 gig data.  The booth is convenient to get to and they put the sim in your phone for you. The sim card I purchased had a cell number that becomes inoperative after the 2 weeks of service I purchased.  Probably there are better plans (with this or other vendors) for people who will be visiting Israel often, that let you keep the same number, but that type of plan was not offered to me.

Here is the booth, and a map of the ground floor:

[image]

Comment: What a rip-off. [Drimsim](https://drimsim.com) would only charge you 20EUR for 2 gigs of data and there are no time limits. Plus you can use the same SIM card in other countries.

Comment: @JonathanReez   This looks really interesting!  By no time limits, do you mean you can have cell service forever with one purchase, as long as you do not use up the data or minutes? (I could not tell from their English website.)

Comment: @JonathanReez  Can you tell what carrier they use in the USA?

Comment: Yes, the SIM does not have an expiration date and does not charge any subscription fees. In the US they use AT&T.

Comment: @JonathanReez. The sim gives you a local number in only one country.  Or is there a way to get a local number in more than one country (with one sim)?

Comment: You only get a UK number, that's true. But personally I never give out my number to anyone as a tourist.

Comment: @JonathanReez.  Oh.  An Israeli number is much more useful when traveling in Israel. Back to 019mobile.com.

Comment: Added a photo and a map. Also, $30 is still a massive rip-off - see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the 019mobile booth, there's this vending machine on the ground floor of the airport:
[image]

next to one of the exits, which sells prepaid mobile SIM cards. I haven't checked the prices myself recently, but they are [reported](https://www.themarker.com/technation/1.2866155) to be exorbitant (news item is from 2016). Note the 019mobile prices are also quite high.

<sub>For reference only, and **not** at the airport: You can get a decent prepaid card for 30 NIS (the HOTTalk package by Hot Mobile: 500 min voice, 500 SMS messages, 5 or 10 GB data, not exactly clear; expires in 10 days). 30 NIS are under 8.5 USD. Again, this is if you actually go to a HOT Mobile store/booth.</sub>